# Drag a div from a static handle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a div draggable with Javascript/JQuery. However, for reasons that I don't think are worthed explaining, I want in draggable from another div.
It happens that this other div (the handle), must not move, as is has the size of the screen and the objective is for it to alays stay covering the whole page.

I can't seem to find an situation like this, which is strange... Is this such a stupid question?

Anyway, can someone tell me how to do this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Comment: Please add some sample code, better if it's a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried applying the `stoppropogation` function to the drag event handler of the parent div?

Comment: Well, I actually tought that I could use a handle outside the element. It turns out that I can't, so, I had to put position: fixed on the handle. To my surprise, position:fixed prevented the handle from moving, thus solving my problem.

Anyway, your suggestion was still useful for other thing, so, thanks :)
(sorry for the 5 hour delay... I had a hard time enabling jQuery UI)

Answer (score 0):

I gonna put an example here , if you want more explanation, comment please.

HTML CODE:

```
<div style="width:1024px: height:768px" id="content"> <!-- this css is only an example -->
  <div class="child" style="width:100px;height:100px;border: 1px solid black"></div>
</div
```

JS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".child").draggable();
});
```

note: Use jquery.js and jqueryUI.js

Comment: I already knew that part, which is a basic drag. My problem was to make a fixed handle, but thanks anyway for the reply :)